# VBA Search value in column in another column, if not found show which, if found copy offset value to offset imput

Tags: excel, vba, copy, match, offset

Can you help me make VBA script that will search values cells in column Sheet1 H:H (every row with data), if it finds the value in Sheet 2 H:H, it will copy offset -6 from sheet 1 and paste offset -6 in sheet 2.

If it dont find anything it will tell me which values it didnt find.

THis is what i have so fare, working but not optimal, firstly i dont get information of the "NOT" Found values, and if it is not found, it will just overwrite and copy that item anyway.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim oCell As Range


Dim i As Long
i = 2

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mellomlagring")


Do While ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    Set oCell = ws2.Range("H:H").Find(what:=ws1.Cells(i, 8))
    If Not oCell Is Nothing Then ws1.Cells(i, 2) = oCell.Offset(0, -6)
    i = i + 1
Loop

Set ws1 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: It looks pretty good so far, honestly. I'm not sure why it would be overwriting anything after the search...

Comment: If you wanted, you could add an `Else` to your `If` statement to add `"Not Found"` or something into `ws1.Cells(i, 2)` when `oCell` is `Nothing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rSourceHCol As Range
    Dim rSourceHCell As Range
    Dim rDestHCol As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirst As String
    Dim sNotFound As String

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rSourceHCol = wsSource.Range("H2", wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
    Set rDestHCol = wsDest.Range("H2", wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))

    If rSourceHCol.Row < 2 Then
        MsgBox "No values present in column H of source sheet " & wsSource.Name
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf rDestHCol.Row < 2 Then
        MsgBox "No values present in column H of destination sheet " & wsDest.Name
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each rSourceHCell In rSourceHCol.Cells
        Set rFound = rDestHCol.Find(rSourceHCell.Value, rDestHCol.Cells(rDestHCol.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If rFound Is Nothing Then
            sNotFound = sNotFound & Chr(10) & rSourceHCell.Value
        Else
            sFirst = rFound.Address
            Do
                rFound.Offset(, -6).Value = rSourceHCell.Offset(, -6).Value
                Set rFound = rDestHCol.FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst
        End If
    Next rSourceHCell

    If Len(sNotFound) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "All values from source data accounted for and updated in destination"
    Else
        MsgBox "The following values in the source data were not found in destination:" & sNotFound
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You my man are truely a hero. Seriously this is spot on, appriciated so much <3 big love :D

Comment: Your script works perfectly. I will thank you again. 

I wonder if you can help me change this to search for 2 columns, and compare those columns, of both are true then it will paste the comment. 

Reason for that is that sometimes I have the same "Tag" it searches for at few places, so the script will paste it at the correct name, but eventually it will be wrong because it is at the wrong location.

Comment: @JonasKorani That should be a relatively easy change.  In the Do Loop, you'd need to add a check for the value in the second column(s).  If you get stuck on that, please start a new question (feel free to provide a link to this one) with what you've tried.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, we have been trying for a while now and can not get it to work :p 

[Link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117368/vba-compare-2-sheets-move-old-comments-to-new-sheet

Master you are my savior please help me with this one last time.