# VBA Compare 2 sheets, move old comments to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Basically i have this script which compare 2 sheets, which compares a value in a column to the new sheet, if it finds the value, it will copy the information from Old sheet "B" to new sheet "B" column.

The script is working flawlessly (Thanks to the author)

I have trying to configure it to search and compare not only 1 column, but 2, if column X AND Y are equal to X AND Y in the new sheet it will do the same task.

The reason for this is that sometimes i have the value it searches for in few different rows, so when it compares it will find it at few places. While this script works perfect only when there are unique "Find" values.

Can you help me to edit so it fits "Find" and compare Column "P" & Column "V" if those are the same in new sheet, it will copy the Values in Column "B" old sheet to "B" new sheet.

```
Sub movecommentsInternode()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim rSourcePCol As Range
Dim rSourcePCell As Range
Dim rDestPCol As Range
Dim rFound As Range
Dim sFirst As String
Dim sNotFound As String

Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsSource = Wb.Sheets("Internode Buffer")
Set wsDest = Wb.Sheets("DataInternode")
Set rSourcePCol = wsSource.Range("P2", wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))
Set rDestPCol = wsDest.Range("P2", wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))


If rSourcePCol.row < 2 Then
    MsgBox "No comment available, therefor no import is needed " ' & wsSource.Name
    Exit Sub
ElseIf rDestPCol.row < 2 Then
    MsgBox "Data Sheet is empty, please import the correct IO-List to be able to merge the comments " ' & wsDest.Name
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each rSourcePCell In rSourcePCol.Cells
    Set rFound = rDestPCol.Find(rSourcePCell.Value, rDestPCol.Cells(rDestPCol.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If rFound Is Nothing Then
        sNotFound = sNotFound & Chr(10) & rSourcePCell.Value
    Else
        sFirst = rFound.Address
        Do
            rFound.Offset(, -14).Value = rSourcePCell.Offset(, -14).Value
            Set rFound = rDestPCol.FindNext(rFound)
        Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst
    End If
Next rSourcePCell

If Len(sNotFound) = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Import completed" & vbCrLf & "All comments have been merged with the new imported IO-List")
Else
    MsgBox ("Import completed" & vbCrLf & "The following tag-comments have not been merged with new IO-List:" & sNotFound)
End If
End Sub
```

Also as a extra thing: Can you help me make it show the missing tags in a list (New sheet) insted of as comment. Will be ackward if there is hundreds of missing tags showing all in Msgbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub movecommentsInternode()

    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim wsMissingTags As Worksheet
    Dim rSourcePCol As Range
    Dim rSourcePCell As Range
    Dim rDestPCol As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirst As String
    Dim sNotFound As String
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    Dim aHeaders() As Variant
    Dim aMissingTags As Variant

    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSource = Wb.Sheets("Internode Buffer")
    Set wsDest = Wb.Sheets("DataInternode")
    Set rSourcePCol = wsSource.Range("P2", wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))
    Set rDestPCol = wsDest.Range("P2", wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))

    If rSourcePCol.Row < 2 Then
        MsgBox "No comment available, therefor no import is needed " ' & wsSource.Name
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf rDestPCol.Row < 2 Then
        MsgBox "Data Sheet is empty, please import the correct IO-List to be able to merge the comments " ' & wsDest.Name
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each rSourcePCell In rSourcePCol.Cells
        bFound = False
        Set rFound = rDestPCol.Find(rSourcePCell.Value, rDestPCol.Cells(rDestPCol.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            sFirst = rFound.Address
            Do
                If rSourcePCell.Offset(, 6).Value = rFound.Offset(, 6).Value Then
                    rFound.Offset(, -14).Value = rSourcePCell.Offset(, -14).Value
                    bFound = True
                End If
                If bFound = True Then Exit Do   'First match for both columns found, exit find loop (this line can be removed if preferred)
                Set rFound = rDestPCol.FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst
        End If
        If bFound = False Then sNotFound = sNotFound & "|" & rSourcePCell.Value & vbTab & rSourcePCell.Offset(, 6).Value
    Next rSourcePCell

    If Len(sNotFound) = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Import completed" & vbCrLf & "All comments have been merged with the new imported IO-List")
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wsMissingTags = Wb.Worksheets("Missing Tags")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If wsMissingTags Is Nothing Then
            'Missing Tags worksheet doesn't exist, create it and add headers
            aHeaders = Array(wsSource.Range("P1").Value, wsSource.Range("V1").Value)
            Set wsMissingTags = Wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=Wb.Worksheets(Wb.Worksheets.Count))
            wsMissingTags.Name = "Missing Tags"
            With wsMissingTags.Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(aHeaders) - LBound(aHeaders) + 1)
                .Value = aHeaders
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            End With
        Else
            'Missing Tags worksheet already exists, clear previous contents (if any)
            wsMissingTags.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).ClearContents
        End If
        aMissingTags = Split(Mid(sNotFound, 2), "|")
        With wsMissingTags.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(aMissingTags) - LBound(aMissingTags) + 1)
            .Value = Application.Transpose(aMissingTags)
            .TextToColumns .Cells, xlDelimited, Tab:=True
        End With
        MsgBox "Import completed" & vbCrLf & "See the Missing Tags worksheet for a list of tag-comments that have not been merged with new IO-List."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Ow my god :D Man, i have no words this is perfect. Thank you all for the help. Seriously you made my day <3

Comment: @tigeravatar Thanka a lot for getting JonasKorani & me out of mess and also for great learning. Now I think I missed exit do loop. Would you please throw some light on my mistakes.

Comment: Thank you to you to AhmedAU it is because of people like you my life get easier :) 

I have to say your scripting method is very slick @tigeravatar you are a big help to this community

Answer (score 0):

It is a fine code. I modified and tried it and find working as per *my understanding of your requirement* The modified full code is:

```
Sub movecommentsInternode()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim rSourceHCol As Range
Dim rDestHCol As Range
Dim rdestHCell As Range
Dim rSourceHCell As Range
Dim rSourceHCol2 As Range   'added
Dim rDestHCol2  As Range    'added
Dim rSourceHCell2 As Range  'added
Dim rdestHCell2 As Range    'added
Dim rFound As Range
Dim sFirst As String
Dim sNotFound As String

Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsSource = Wb.Sheets("Internode Buffer")
Set wsDest = Wb.Sheets("DataInternode")
Set rSourceHCol = wsSource.Range("H2", wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
Set rDestHCol = wsDest.Range("H2", wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
'Next two lines added
Set rSourceHCol2 = wsSource.Range("V2", wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp))
Set rDestHCol2 = wsDest.Range("V2", wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp))


If rSourceHCol.Row < 2 Or rSourceHCol2.Row < 2 Then  ' condition modified
    MsgBox "No comment available, therefor no import is needed " ' & wsSource.Name
    Exit Sub
ElseIf rDestHCol.Row < 2 Or rDestHCol2.Row < 2 Then  ' condition modified
    MsgBox "Data Sheet is empty, please import the correct IO-List to be able to merge the comments " ' & wsDest.Name
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each rSourceHCell In rSourceHCol.Cells
Set rSourceHCell2 = rSourceHCell.Offset(0, 14)     'corresponding value in V Col Source Sheet
    Set rFound = rDestHCol.Find(rSourceHCell.Value, rDestHCol.Cells(rDestHCol.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If rFound Is Nothing Then
        sNotFound = sNotFound & Chr(10) & rSourceHCell.Value
    Else
        sFirst = rFound.Address
        Do
            'Next two lines and if clause added
            Set rdestHCell2 = rFound.Offset(0, 14)             'corresponding value in V Col Destination Sheet

                If rSourceHCell2.Value = rdestHCell2.Value Then  ' added
                rFound.Offset(0, -6).Value = rSourceHCell.Offset(0, -6).Value     'offset from H to B
                End If

            Set rFound = rDestHCol.FindNext(rFound)
        Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst
    End If
Next rSourceHCell

If Len(sNotFound) = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Import completed" & vbCrLf & "All comments have been merged with the new imported IO-List")
Else
    MsgBox ("Import completed" & vbCrLf & "The following tag-comments have not been merged with new IO-List:" & sNotFound)
End If
End Sub
```

Edit: line `Set rSourceHCell2 = rSourceHCell.Offset(0, 14)` moved after line `For Each rSourceHCell In rSourceHCol.Cells` . If it does not work try to use `If StrComp(rSourceHCell2.Value, rDestHCell2.Value) = 0 Then` in place of  `If rSourceHCell2.Value = rdestHCell2.Value Then`

Comment: Hey man, thank you for the help,

I have been trying for few hours to tweak your script a little. It is not working as intended. 

The script is moving the comment to every place which has the value of "H", so example if H5 is 79LOG002DA, and V5 is Con1, It copies it to every place where it finds 79LOG002DA, even tho  if V5 are Con5 or Con6.

I need it only to copy if it finds 79LOG002DA & Con1 from old place, and paste it only at 79LOG002DA & Con1 in new sheet. 

If 79LOG002DA & Con1 is not found, it will tell me that tag 79LOG002DA  is not valid (Which it already does)

Comment: Your logic sounds right to me, but somehow it is not working as intendend. So if it searches for H (or P, same thing) and it confirms that value of H is in the new sheet it will check with V, if V are equal on both it will paste old B to new B. 

But this script is doing it halfway, it checks for H (P), but pastes value of H, everywhere it finds H, even if V is not equal.

Source H and V are not equal in my situation:
H5 = 79LOG002DA & V5 = Con1,
H6 = 79LOG002DA & V6 = Con5 
etc

Comment: I asked the author, and he told me this 
"@JonasKorani That should be a relatively easy change. In the Do Loop, you'd need to add a check for the value in the second column(s). "

@tigeravatar 
But i didnt manage to get it

[Link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761475/vba-search-value-in-column-in-another-column-if-not-found-show-which-if-found)

Comment: it still fills comments, independent on what is in column V :/ 
This is example 

H10 = 79LOG002A, V10 = Con1, H11 = 79LOG002A, V11 = Con2. 

It takes the comment added to B10 - puts it in new sheet for Row10 & Row 11, 
H is equal, but V is not. so it shouldent do that, it should only put to Row10